# Segmentation Fault while using memcpy in C

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, memcpy

I am using memcpy function in my code and getting Segmentation Fault error when i run it. Following goes the code.

`memcpy ((void *) ((unsigned int) core_data + (width * height * bpp)), (void *) core_data, (width * height * bpp));`

core_data is **unsigned short** pointer and height, width and bpp are **static int** type. The value of (width * height * bpp) is **8355840**. When i reduce this value, to say 10, the error is resolved. But in real case scenario i have to keep the value to 8355840.
any solution ?

thanks

Comment: Did you allocate memory to `core_data`, or at least initialised it to point to allocated memory somehow,  before copying to it?

Comment: What type is `bpp` if I may ask?

Comment: Why the cast to `(unsigned int)`?

Comment: @alk, no i haven't allocated any memory to core_data!

Comment: bpp is of static int type

Comment: Can I see the definitions of all of the variables used?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? You do realize that `memcpy` copies data from the source to the destination? The source must be readable and the destination must be large enough to receive the data.

Comment: i have typecasted core_data as it is of unsigned short type. i wanted it to be of unsigned int.

Comment: @Sid Does not allacte memory for `core_data`? Then that is why your program crash.

Comment: You copying all that into an unsigned short? o.O

Comment: "core_data is unsigned short pointer " and yet you cast it to unsigned int.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please show more code.

Your use of casts is *very strange*, and there's too many parentheses in there to make it readable. You should rarely cast pointers to integers, and if you do you must use e.g. `intptr_t` to make sure that the integer is large enough to hold the pointer value (the number of bits in `unsigned int` might be smaller than the number of bits in `unsigned short *`), else the pointer is destroyed when casting.

It should just be:

```
memcpy(core_data + width * height * bpp, core_data, width * height * bpp);
```

Pointer arithmetic in C is a (very good) thing, you don't need to cast to/from integers just to compute addresses. Remember that pointer arithmetic is "scaled" by the size of the pointed-to objects, which might mean that `bpp` should just be 1 if `core_data` is a pointer to 16-bit integers and your pixels are 16-bit.

Also, of course, make sure that the memory is properly allocated, i.e. that you do:

```
core_data = malloc(2 * width * height * bpp * sizeof *core_data);
```

and have it return non-`NULL`.

Of course, we can further boost the niceness of this code by factoring out the size of one "frame":

```
const size_t frame_size = width * height * bpp;
```

Then we can use this wherever needed, to make it more clear what's going on:

```
core_data = malloc(2 * frame_size);
```

and:

```
memcpy(core_data + frame_size, core_data, frame_size);
```

Comment: in this case bpp is 4, not 1.

Comment: @Sid But what does `bpp` *mean*? Is it "bytes per pixel"? If so, then the `core_data` pointer should be `uint8_t *`. Else, if pixels are 32-bit, why not make `core_data` into `uint32_t *` and drop `bpp`?

Comment: +1 - casts were so weird I didn't even stop to think what the pointer arithmetic was for :)